# What is the minimum amount of Ada needed to stake?

Tags: stake-pool, staking

What is the **minimum** (lowest) amount of Ada needed to **stake**?

Could you have the delegation fee + 0.00001 Ada?  Where is this referenced?

Answer (score 5):

There is an initial 2.17 ADA fee when delegating a wallet for the first time.

Here's the breakdown of that: 2 ADA deposit goes towards registering your stake address on the blockchain and ~0.17 ADA is the transaction fee.

*Note: the 2 ADA deposit is refundable upon unstaking*

Happy staking!

The 2 ADA (current configuration of "keyDeposit") comes from [the mainnet genesis file](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/3670619/download/1/mainnet-shelley-genesis.json).

Comment: This is great.  Do you know the source of info for this, in the specs?

Comment: The 2 ADA deposit comes from the "keyDeposit" param [here](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/3670619/download/1/mainnet-shelley-genesis.json)

Answer (score 2):

There is no *staking* minimum, but there is a UTXO minimum. With current [protocol parameters](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/governance/cardano-improvement-proposals/cip-0009/), any UTXO on Cardano must have a minimum of 1 ADA (minUTXOvalue).

So while possible in principle, there is currently no way to create a UTXO, and thus to stake, anything less than 1 ADA.

Comment: Thanks. I helped onboard a friend to setup a Cardano wallet, had 2.83 Ada in there, had him setup staking.  The .833 Ada delegation fee went thru, however the 2 Ada never appeared back in his wallet, although on the blockchain the transaction went thru.  I opened up a ticket in ccvault wallet to perhaps fix this display or add a warning.  https://github.com/ccwalletio/tracker/issues/68

Comment: Just to be clear - the staking certificate (delegation) fee is 2 ADA. Whatever is leftover in the wallet will then be staked, plus whatever you add to the wallet. If you'd like to receive the 2 ADA back you would have to de-register your staking key. Think of the 2 ADA as a deposit for staking that you will get back if you choose to unstake.